# jquery rendering the spinner slowly on google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to show a spinner when a button is clicked to indicate that browser is performing actions behind the scenes.spinner is showed right after I click the button on the Firefox browser but not on the Google Chrome browser. On Google Chrome browser there is a delay of 8 seconds. I have debugged it on developer tools while the action has performed but I do see that class attribute is been added to the html code right when the button is clicked.

Here is my markup:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="loadSpinner" style="display:none;"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn spinnerEvent" >On</button>
     
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", "button.spinnerEvent", function(event){
            $('#loadSpinner').addClass('show');  //LOADS THE SPINNER
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #loadSpinner.show{
            background:#000 url(../images/spinner-small.gif) no-repeat center center;
            background-color: transparent;
            height: 128px;
            width: 128px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1000;
            left: 50%;
            top: 25%;
            margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: You're referencing code in your JS that doesn't exist in your markup. Can you please clean up your code and provide us with a [mcve]?

Comment: I have actually tested my code on jsFiddle and I see that spinner is displayed for a button click. I do not understand why there is a delay in the application.

Comment: Your code works fine as it is. Where's your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working fiddle with minor changes to your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/783gyyou/2/

**HTML:**

Removed `display:none` as that inline style will take precedence over your CSS style defined in the `style` tag

```
<div id="loadSpinner"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn spinnerEvent">On</button>
```

**CSS:**

Setting all styles in the style tag.

```
#loadSpinner {
    display: none;
}

#loadSpinner.show {
    background: #000 url(../images/spinner-small.gif) no-repeat center center;
    background-color: red; /*changed from transparent to red so you can see the div, even though I don't have access to the actual image*/
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    display: block;
}
```

In Google Chrome, the loading div appears right away on click of the button.

If you are still experiencing problems, try to preload the spinning image on the page.  It may simply be that the image itself is taking some time to load and there is not a delay in your code.

Here are some tips on how to preload CSS images used as backgrounds after the page loads: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/

Comment: thank you for the response. As you said I am still experiencing the delay. I am also not successful in writing the code for preload spinning image. could please help me with preload of a spinner image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1588142 here are some tips I found to try: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/  Hope it works out for you.